# how to populate 2 arrays and sort them by their time created using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    const PostSchema = new Schema({
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users'
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        location: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        userid: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phonenumber: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        language: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        postcode: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
        ,
        price: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }

    })

    module.exports = HousingPost = mongoose.model('housingModel', PostSchema);



const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const PostSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phonenumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    language: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    make: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    condition: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postcode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    links: [{ type: String }],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = ForSalePosts = mongoose.model('forSaleModel', PostSchema);


const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AllPostsSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    forsaleposts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'forSaleModel'
    }],
    housingposts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'housingModel'
    }],

})


module.exports = AllPosts = mongoose.model('allposts', AllPostsSchema)



const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },


})

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
```

these are the models i have. everytime a post created in any category, their user and post ids are being pushed into category model. however i'd like to join these tables and sort them by data like :

```
 AllPosts.findOne({ user: req.params.userid })
        .populate('housingposts')
        .populate('forsaleposts')
        .sort()
        .then(posts => res.json(posts))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nopostfound: 'There is no housing posts' }))
```

i need this to return allposts by logged in user and list them by date. AllPosts schema doesnt have a date field but HousingPosts and ForSalePosts do.

Comment: Please share collection ?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar all the collections are above

Answer (score 1):

So what you're looking for is:

```
AllPosts.findOne({ user: req.params.userid })
.populate({path: 'housingposts', options: { sort: { 'date': -1 } } })
```

Also see [Mongoose JS](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) for more details

Comment: No, I am looking for :                             
  ```AllPosts.findOne({ user: req.params.userid })
.populate({path: 'housingposts', options: { sort: { 'date': -1 } } })```                                                                                 
 and                                                        
 ```AllPosts.findOne({ user: req.params.userid })
.populate({path: 'forsaleposts', options: { sort: { 'date': -1 } } })``` combined

Comment: I want to combine forsaleposts and housing posts under category and sort them by date

Comment: Did you try doing:
`AllPosts.findOne({ user: req.params.userid })
.populate({path: 'housingposts', options: { sort: { 'date': -1 } } }).populate({path: 'forsaleposts', options: { sort: { 'date': -1 } } })` ?
As per Mongoose documentation
> The Document#populate() method supports chaining, so you can chain multiple populate() calls together.
Documentation - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_an_existing_mongoose_document